# Cmake generator expression TARGET_PROPERTY of external project

Tags: cmake

I need to use a property from an external project. So far I'm successfully doing that this way:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    some_ep_name
    ...
)

# Get source dir
ExternalProject_Get_Property(some_ep_name SOURCE_DIR)

# Set source dir value into less generically named variable
set(SOME_EP_NAME_SOURCE_DIR "${SOURCE_DIR}")
```

This works, but it seems unnecessarily verbose, and it annoys me a little. I was *hoping* I could use a generator expression, like so:

```
"$<TARGET_PROPERTY:some_ep_name,SOURCE_DIR>"
```

But it seems like this doesn't work. Before I give up, I wanted to check if I was doing something wrong or if anyone knows a better way.

Answer (score 0):

All "properties" of ExternalProject are known at configuration time. So they don't require support of generator expressions, which main intention is usage for values **not known at configuration time** (but known at build time).

If you found "unnecessarily verbose" having *several lines of code* for save external project' property into the variable, you may create a macro/function for incorporate all these lines. Then calling the macro/function will use only single line of code:

```
function(ExternalProject_Property_to_Var VAR eproject prop)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(${eproject} ${eprop})
    set(${VAR} ${${eprop}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

...
ExternalProject_Property_to_Var(SOME_EP_NAME_SOURCE_DIR some_ep_name SOURCE_DIR)
```